# Mouse on center of moving image on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am making for school a star catching game. 
I want the enviroment to change dynamicly so that when i resize browser windows the game will resize with it.

I got the following running code:
http://jsfiddle.net/xigolle/yA74f/

The only problem with that is that the mouse isn't center on the witch. 
What is the best way for me to get the mouse on the center on every size?

The problem lays for sure in this part:

```
 ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, canvas.width/10, canvas.height/10);
```

The size of the browser window i get from a event listener who activates when i resize.

And the value is put in canvas.width and canvas.height.

I hope you guys can help me :)

For any more question or unclearance please ask :)

Comment: You just want your mouse in the center of your witch, and you want the picture of the witch that can have different size ? So it can be smaller or bigger ? Am I right ?

Comment: Yes that is true. The image of the which should be changed when the window size is changed :) i know i dont keep the ratio atm. But if you can resolve that problem to i would be so gratefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems

The first is your use of drawImage

```
ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, canvas.width/10, canvas.height/10);
```

This is going to rescale the witch image in a way that does not keep the proportions, which is why when resizing the window the witch either squishes or expands

You should resize the image based on a ratio of the original image size and original canvas size. Then use that ratio times the new canvas size to get the right image size.

```
//Original canvas width/height
var initialWidth = 500, initialHeight = 500;
var initialImgWidth = 120, initialImgHeight = 65;
var wRatio =  initialImgWidth/initialWidth, hRatio = initialImgHeight/initialHeight;
...
ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, canvas.width*wRatio, canvas.height*hRatio);
```

Now that we have the image resize resolved now we can center the image on the mouse
Now to center you have to take the mouse x/y and minus each with 1/2 of width/height of the rescaled witch respectively

```
Witch.x = event.pageX-((canvas.width*wRatio)/2);
Witch.y = event.pageY-((canvas.height*hRatio)/2);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yA74f/2/)

**EDIT**

My rescale calculations were wrong, for now to scale the image for now just scale it by its original dimensions

```
var imgWScale = initialImgWidth/2;
var imgHScale = initialImgHeight/2;
...
ctx.drawImage(img, this.x, this.y, imgWScale,imgHScale);
...
Witch.x = event.pageX-(imgWScale/2);
Witch.y = event.pageY-(imgHScale/2);
```

Just remember to center just get the images width/height and divide in half and then take that from the mouse coordinates.

Comment: the witch still will scale wrongly you will have to figure out the correct calculations. For now you can just scale the width/height of the image itself for now. Edited the answer to show